# C# - Why implement standard exception constructors?

Tags: c#, exception, coding-style

From MSDN, code analysis warning CA1032:

```
Exception types must implement the following constructors: 
public NewException() 
public NewException(string) 
public NewException(string, Exception) 
protected or private NewException(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)
```

I understand the purpose behind the serialization constructor, but is the rationale behind "requiring" the others? Why shouldn't I just define whatever constructors make sense for usage of my exception? What if I never want to throw MyException without passing in a message- why should I define a parameterless constructor? What if I want MyException to have an int property and I only want constructors that initialize that property?

Answer (score 18):

This is a warning, not a requirement.  It's basically [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  Providing all 4 makes it easier for people used to "regular" C# exceptions to use yours.  If you have a good reason to ignore the guideline, do so.  But it will break certain usage scenarios, and make your class a little less intuitive.

Comment: It won't just make it less intuitive - it will specifically disable it from working, either in exception remoting scenarios or when the caller needs to use it as a wrapper for another exception.

Comment: True.  The OP /may/ have a good reason not to care about those, but probably not.

Comment: Agree. Important to remember here is that the Exception classes are a vital part of the API. As a comparison, in Java you can explicitly declare what exceptions that could be expected (I'm not saying that is better tho...) while in C# you have to either rely on documentation or very clear self-explanatory exceptions. Hence the guideline.

Answer (score 12):

You have gotten some good answers. I just want to add that providing these extra constructors does not necessarily require a lot of coding. Since they are already implemented in the base class, you can simply let that one do the work:

```
public class MyCustomException : Exception
{
    public MyCustomException() : base() { }
    public MyCustomException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public MyCustomException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
    // and so on...
}
```

So you will only need to implement code where the behaviour of your exception deviates from that of the base class.

Comment: How can this be the top answer? It's doesn't even try to answer the "Why" part of the question. With the suggested approach, the codebase would be full of boilerplate code that provides no real business value in my opinion, and creates more complexity.

Comment: I agree with your surprise regarding how this has more upvotes, @JimAho; I would say that the answers by jrista, Matthew and Daniel do a good job of answering the "why", so I saw no need to repeat that. I don't agree that they don't provide business value. Those constructurs (that are expected by some generic routing, as mentioned in other answers) are not available unless you declare them. Boilerplate, yes, but not without value.

Answer (score 9):

The parameterless and Serialization constructors are used by generic "exception routing" code that needs to move exceptions around between domains (e.g. across the internet between a service and a client).

The one that takes another `Exception` is so that it is possible to chain all exceptions via the `InnerException` property.

Finally, there's the one that takes a message string, which helps to make use of exceptions reasonably consistent.

Comment: I was not aware that the parameterless constructor was required for the exception routing; I thought the serialization constructor handled that. This is one area of exceptions that I have zero experience or knowledge in.

Comment: It depends what serializer you use - XmlSerializer requires a parameterless constructor, the other methods don't.

Comment: excellent answer, did not know this,  I have always omitted the default constructor since I want to force users to supply a message when throwing the Exception

Answer (score 5):

Implementing the standard exception constructors allow people to use your exception in a standard, familiar way that is built into all existing .NET exceptions. The first three can be optional, if for some reason you don't want one of them to be used (although why you would want that I couldn't fathom.) However, the last one is the deserialization constructor, and if you wish your exception to be supported in any kind of distributed environment (.NET Remoting, ASP.NET Web Services, WCF, etc.), then its is pretty much essential.

Without a deserialization constructor and the [Serializable] attribute, your exceptions won't function in a distributed environment, and could possibly cause other problems. Given that, and the aspect of familiarity to well-versed C# developers, its best to implement at least the 4 standard exception constructors, and mark your exceptions with [Serializable].

Comment: You should implement the serialization ctor EVEN if you don't plan on being in a distributed scenario. Since it's used in remoting to pass the exceptions between domains, it may be called inside your process if you happen to have several AppDomains (intra appdomains communication is likely to become the last use case of remoting, since it's being slowly replaced by WCF for Out Of Process calls). You never know how your code will be called. If someone wishes to have your code called inside a plugin in an app, it will end up in another appDomain and you'll need this constructor.

Comment: Very good point. Its generally just a best practice to implement the standard constructors and serializability because .NET will use and possibly "rethrow" or recreate and wrap your exceptions in a wide variety of places.

Answer (score 2):

It's just another [Cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult).
Someone once decided it's a good idea to make so (obviously most probably having strong relevant justifying experience) but with years of language evolution real reasoning has been replaced by repeating the dogma: just do as we used to do, don't ask.

Do we really want to allow custom exception being created with uninitialized custom property (if one presented)?

Do we really want to support serialization of our custom exception?

One aspect we most probably want is possibility to instantiate custom exception from client code to make it possible to test how our exception is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because. (Because from other answers, the parameterless constructor is required for exception routing.)

I'm in the same place, and I don't want to accidentally construct an exception without my error code parameter. So here's what I did:

```
public class MyException : ArgumentException
{
    [Obsolete("Use a constructor that takes an ErrorCode instead")]
    public MyException() { }

    [Obsolete("Use a constructor that takes an ErrorCode instead")]
    public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }

    [Obsolete("Use a constructor that takes an ErrorCode instead")]
    public MyException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    public MyException(ErrorCode errorCode, string message) : base(message) { /* use error code */ }

    public MyException(ErrorCode errorCode, string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { /* use error code */ }

    protected MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            // error code stuff
        }
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        if (info != null)
        {
            // error code stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: issue is that everytime you compile you will get a warning message about the code being marked Obsolete

Answer (score -1):

Well, the constructor that takes an inner exception is pretty much necessary to make a custom exception properly usable.  Without it, if someone caught your exception, they couldn't fire off a more descriptive or appropriate exception while preserving your original one (and the information it carries, like the stack trace.)

Comment: I think you have this backwards - the one that takes an inner exception is so that if your code catches another exception, you can wrap your exception around it